# How to get a conditionally visible Checkbox in Google Sheets to work correctly?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I only want to have this checkbox visible if there is something in another cell.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B4),"",FALSE)
```

This works fine as a conditionally visible checkbox, but the issue is that clicking on the checkbox doesn't change the checkbox state.

Is there a way to have this checkbox be conditionally visible and also functionally work (allowing the user to click it & change the state)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put a checkbox to a cell when the cell "B4" is not empty.
- You want to remove the checkbox from the cell when the cell "B4" is empty.
- You want to check and uncheck for the checkbox.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script from your tag.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Issue and workaround:

When `=IF(ISBLANK(B4),"",FALSE)` is used, the checkbox is cannot be checked. This has already been mentioned in your question. In order to avoid this, as a workaround, I would like to propose to use Google Apps Script and the OnEdit event trigger. I thought that by this, your goal can be achieved.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following sample script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And please set the variables of `checkboxCell` and `sheetName`. Then, please edit the cell of `B4`. By this, the script is automatically run by the OnEdit Event trigger.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const checkboxCell = "C4"; // Please set the cell for putting the checkbox.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name you want to put the checkbox.

  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == sheetName && range.getA1Notation() == "B4") {
    const value = range.getValue();
    sheet.getRange(checkboxCell)[value === "" ? "removeCheckboxes" : "insertCheckboxes"]();
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, when the script is run, when the edit cell is `B4` on the sheet of `sheetName`, when the cell `B4` is empty, the checkbox is removed from the cell `checkboxCell`. When the cell `B4` is NOT empty, the checkbox is put to the cell `checkboxCell`.
- This is a simple sample script for confirming whether your goal in your question (`Is there a way to have this checkbox be conditionally visible and also functionally work (allowing the user to click it & change the state)?`) can be achieved by Google Apps Script. So please modify this for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [insertCheckboxes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#insertcheckboxes)
- [removeCheckboxes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#removecheckboxes)